# cannot disable notification sound when galaxy s10+ starts to charge

Tags: notifications

Every time I place the S10+ in the wireless charger, or remove it from the charger, the phone barks at me. I cannot locate a place to disable this. If I turn the sound for Notifications off, the sound disappears, but I do not want to disable all Notifications, just this one.